# p:button to toggle inplace input

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to get a button that will switch an p:inplace item. I'm trying to use the toggle function but am not having any luck.

```
<p:inplace widgetVar="X" >
  <p:inputText  value="test"></p:inputText>
 </p:inplace>

<p:button value="toggle" onclick="X.toggle()" />
```

When I do this I get the following message in my browser's console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fadeOut' of undefined primefaces.js.jsf:18
PrimeFaces.widget.Inplace.PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend.toggle primefaces.js.jsf:18
onclick

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a bug with the default effect. Change the effect to one of the other standard effects and see if that gets you going.

```
<p:inplace widgetVar="X" effect="clip">
  <p:inputText  value="test"></p:inputText>
</p:inplace>
```

The available effects as defined in the user manual:

```
• blind
• clip
• drop
• explode
• fold
• puff
• slide
• scale
• bounce
• highlight
• pulsate
• shake
• size
• transfer
```

Comment: This did not do it.  I've updated to primefaces 3.4.1 and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle javascript function looks weird. It only supports 3 effect values. It also requires two first arguments - element to show and element to hide. Have no clue how to use it.

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Inplace.prototype.toggle = function(elToShow, elToHide, callback) {
    var _self = this;
    if(this.cfg.effect == 'fade') {
        elToHide.fadeOut(this.cfg.effectSpeed,
                function(){
            elToShow.fadeIn(_self.cfg.effectSpeed);

            if(callback)
                callback.call(_self);
        });
    }
    else if(this.cfg.effect == 'slide') {
        elToHide.slideUp(this.cfg.effectSpeed,
                function(){
            elToShow.slideDown(_self.cfg.effectSpeed);
        });
    }
    else if(this.cfg.effect == 'none') {
        elToHide.hide();
        elToShow.show();
    }
}
```

I can recommend at least one workaround (pretty hackish as it uses internal ids of tag's generated markup but worked for me (PrimeFaces 3.5):

```
<p:inplace event="none" id="xId">
    <h:inputText value="test"/>
</p:inplace>
<p:commandButton value="Toggle" 
    oncomplete="$('#xId_content,#xId_display').toggle()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this, works for me:

```
    <p:commandLink onclick="PF('X').toggle()" title="Toggle"></p:commandLink>
```

it will toggle your widgetvar for you.

Comment: And it will do more...It will submit a post to the server which is afaics not what you want. No need to use a commandLink at all here. And a button != link. Better to look into the PF docs on how to use a (command)Button and only do client-side javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of PrimeFaces (from 4 and up iirc) have the option to add `type="button"` to the `p:commandButton` and it then does not call anything on the server just the client side javascript

Answer (score -1):

Very simple: instead of `toggle()` you have to use the `show()`, resp. `hide()` functions, in your case:

```
<p:button value="toggle" onclick="X.show()" />
```

Comment: Why? toggle() still is is a valid client-side api call.(see page 276 of the 6.1 docs)

Comment: Yes, but as "jhaley" correctly asks: "It only supports 3 effect values."

Comment: But you don't use any other effects either... So overriding the effects is the way to go.